# MySQL group by percent with where clause

Tags: mysql, count, percentage

i have a table Products
with following fields and values:

```
  ID | Productname | Productprice | Supplier | Available |
+----+-------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Tshirt      | 20           | CompanyA |    Yes    |
|  2 | Pants       | 45           | CompanyA |    Yes    |
|  3 | Shoes       | 95           | CompanyB |    Yes    |
|  4 | Socks       | 12           | CompanyA |     No    |
|  5 | Trainer     | 50           | CompanyA |    Yes    |
```

How to query how many products belong to CompanyA with status Available=Yes in percentage?

Comment: What do you mean by percentage

Comment: Can you provide expected output

Comment: Percentage of what exactly? Is the answer here 60% (3 of 5 rows in the table are Company A and available) or 75% (3 of 4 Company A products are available) or...?

Comment: Expected output: (Company=A, Available=Yes)  
Products Available by CompanyA = 3   
Expected output by percentage (from total products count, Company=A, Available=Yes)  
Products Available by CompanyA = xx%

Comment: Still... is the correct result 60% or 75%?

Comment: The correct result for percentage would be 60%
> Total product count = 5, Where Supplier = 'CompanyA' and Available = 'Yes"

Comment: @willhelm2 - Put the examples of expected results in the question, not the comments. Comments aren't very visible, and are frequently deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the percentage of available products appearing in `CompanyA` from the overall products, you may use a subquery to calculate that.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products`) as `percentage`
FROM `products` WHERE `supplier` = 'CompanyA' and `available` = 'Yes'
```

Based on your data sample, the above query should return

```
   percentage
+-----+-------+
|   60.0000   |
```

Comment: Thank you. This provides correct output.

Comment: @willhelm2 You're welcome! Glad I managed to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that by "percent" you mean the number of rows with Available among all rows of that company:

```
select Supplier, TotalAvailable / Total from(
   select 
      Supplier, 
      sum( if(Available = 'Yes',1,0) ) as TotalAvailable, 
      count(*) as Total
   from
      Products
   where
      Supplier = 'CompanyA'
   group by
      Supplier
) a
```

Or you can use

```
select 
   Supplier, 
   sum( if(Available = 'Yes',1,0) ) / count(*) as Percent 
from
   Products
where
   Supplier = 'CompanyA'
group by
   Supplier
```

Mind that you must handle the "Percent" as it fits for your intentions: multiply by 100, cut the decimals for representation etc.

Comment: Maybe you should compare `Available` with `'Yes'`.

Comment: You are right. He is using text representation for boolean values.

Comment: I added the condition on the query.

Comment: This is not giving the right percentage, like it can't count Yes - text representation